# K&R chapter 8, readdir function

Tags: c

I'm stuck at this function (found in `fsize()` example in K&R chapter 8):

```
#include <sys/dir.h>
/* local directory structure */
/* readdir: read directory entries in sequence */
Dirent *readdir(DIR *dp)
{
    struct direct dirbuf; /* local directory structure */
    static Dirent d;      /* return: portable structure */

    while (read(dp->fd, (char *) &dirbuf, sizeof(dirbuf)) == sizeof(dirbuf)) {
        if (dirbuf.d_ino == 0) /* slot not in use */
            continue;
        d.ino = dirbuf.d_ino;
        strncpy(d.name, dirbuf.d_name, DIRSIZ);
        d.name[DIRSIZ] = '\0'; /* ensure termination */
        return &d;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

In this function `Dirent` and `DIR` are custom structs written by K&R (not the one found in dirent.h):

```
typedef struct { /* portable directory entry */
  long ino;    /* inode number */
  char name[NAME_MAX+1];    /* name + '\0' terminator */
} Dirent;

typedef struct {     
  int fd;
  Dirent d;
} DIR;
```

When I use the code in the book, it runs fine but there were two problems (questions):

- The file listing process does not happen recursively. It only applies once with the current directory.
- I can't understand the line with `read()` function as above.
  1) If `dp->fd` is a directory's, `read()` returns with errno 21 (directory error),
  2) How could a `read()` like that fill in the memory structure `dirbuf`, doesn't it suppose to read only character/byte of some sorts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Think for a moment about the costs of a recursive structure.
You would need a list of sub directories, for each dirent. That increases your memory requirements drastically, as well as complexities your memory allocation (can't use stack-allocated structs anymore, you must use `malloc`/`free`) code.

For this reason, I say that #1 Is invalid.

Not entirely sure if this is homework, but I cannot reproduce #2, so for now I'll leave it alone.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that K&R took the simplest approach possible. They didn't do much (if any) of allocating/freeing memory but just normal recursive, pretty standard stuff...for 1) and 2), without a copy of the book it's quite hard to explain...By the way, this is not my homework :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Calling the function once returns the "next" directory entry. It is intended to be called repeatedly - once for each directory entry.
2. The read syscall (declared in unistd.h) cannot be given a directory file descriptor. This is most likely a different "read" function. dirbuf is declared in the function, so it isn't read only.

Comment: Thanks. I tested the code with a nested directory structure, but fsize() didn't go deeper into sub-directories. 2) I agree that read() in unistd.h doesn't take a dir's file descriptor, but it appears that the code used this one. What's I'm not quite sure is why they passed in a struct in place of the 2nd parameter (void* in the declaration) and how read() works to fill in dirbuf? I thought that dp->fd will point to some sort of similar memory structure, but if that's the case, it's not quite as portable as they said when using these structs...