# readdir routine-local directory vs portable dirctory(p.184 K&R)

Tags: c, readdir

Why does readdir routine need struct direct?
[p  184 K&R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oberS.jpg)
For what reason we need the struct direct and can't only use the struct Dirent?
The definition of Dirent: [p 180 K&R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ub08.jpg)
The definition of direct: [p.183 K&R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLtsg.jpg)

Comment: my `readdir()` returns `struct dirent *`. I don't understand your question...

Comment: The question is why we need the struct direct

Comment: "*Why readdir routine returns direct and not Dirent?*" K&R's `readdir()` *does* return a pointer to a `Dirent`. It does *not* return a `struct direct`. This is obvious from the 1st screen shot you link. What are you talking? (also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063717/kr-chapter-8-readdir-function)

Comment: I edited  the question.

Comment: "*Why does readdir routine need struct direct?*" read the text in the K&R book just before the `readdir()` code to learn why.

Comment: The intention why it was implemented exactly this way might have been to abstract away things like inodes from the application layer, which just is interested in the file's names.

Answer (score 2):

Because K&R C is from the 70's (yeah good old time...), and in K&R C the standard library did not contains things like `readdir` not `struct dirent`, so programmers had to use directly `read` to process a directory and use the low level `struct direct`.

The code you show is just an example of how to wrap that low level io in a higher level `readdir` function - and if I correctly read it is neither the currect `readdir` function, nor the current `dirent` struct...

So **beware**: I loved K&R in the early 80's, but have only use ANSI C and later ISO C for more than 30 years. Maybe you should try and find a slightly more recent book to learn C...